# Displacement time graph- aerodynamic drag

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, drag, free-fall

In the displacement vs time graph of an object in free fall, the parabola with aerodynamic drag is much more steeper on the way downwards of the object than the parabola in which air friction is ignored. Why is this so?

[image]

Comment: Because drag slows the object down, so it takes longer to fall (and it's not a parabola with drag present).

Comment: @ChetMiller please see the new image I have added

Comment: So this is for an object given an initial upward velocity, right?  Are you able to write the differential equation for the rate of change of upward velocity as a function of g and an air drag coefficient?